# How can I initialize similar structs with the same function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have some structs that start with a `void *buffer` and the next members can be of different types:

```
struct A {
    void *buffer;
    type_x *x;
    type_y *y;
};

struct B {
    void *buffer;
    type_w *w;
    type_y *y;
    type_z *z;
};
```

The buffer from `struct A` will store n elements of type `type_x`, followed by n elements of `type_y`. The other members, `type_x *x` and `type_y *y`, will point to those arrays, respectively. Analogous for `struct B`.

What I'm currently doing is something like this:

```
void allocate(struct B **b, unsigned int n) {
    (*b)->buffer = calloc(n * (sizeof(type_w) + sizeof(type_y) + sizeof(type_z));

    (*b)->w = (type_w *) (*b)->buffer;
    (*b)->y = (type_y *) ((*b)->w + n);
    (*b)->z = (type_z *) ((*b)->y + n);
}
```

Is there any way to create a function to achieve this? The function should receive as arguments a pointer to one of these structs (`void *s`) and an int, like this:

```
void allocate(void *s, unsigned int n) {
    // MAGIC
}
```

Some other options I've considered:

1. Create `void allocate(void *buffer, int n, ...)` and give it pointers to the pointers of the struct. The problem with this is that I have to give it void * pointers, so I would have to give it the size of every type as well.
2. Create `void *create_struct(StructType type)` (where StructType is an enum) but I would have to code the case for every struct anyway and I want to be able to define new structs and not have to write aditional code.

I'm trying to do this as I will have many structs, and because the allocate function does basically the same thing for every struct I thought there may be a "cleaner" way to do it.

Also, I know that I can just remove the buffer and allocate memory directly to all the members, but I want to do it this way so data is stored contiguously.

Comment: This is mostly a bad idea...  But how about a macro to pass the size? e.g. `#define alloc(ptr) __alloc((ptr), sizeof((ptr)))`?

Comment: You have alignment issue in your original code. (`n = 3`, `type_w = char` and `type_y = double`)

Comment: You also violate effective type rules when you access as a different type. Also you loose the pointer once your function returns. Before srating sophisticated pointer/struct work, please get the basics right.

Comment: @user9000: That macro will just allocate the size of a pointer - unlikely this is what OP wants. Also identifiers with starting with double `_` are reserved for the implementation. They shall not be used by user code.

Comment: The magic you're looking for is something you must code yourself. What you're already doing is likely the cleanest code that can be done without resorting to compiler extensions such as the [`typeof` GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) that facilitates some magical things like the Linux kernel's [`container_of` macro](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html). Otherwise you deal with separate initialization functions, and you still need to pass a size to the function as well as `n` and the init function itself.

Comment: @Olaf I think he meant to use a macro for option 1 (I would only have to pass the pointers to the members and then get the size of each one automatically). With respect to loosing the pointer and the alignment issue, I wrote this just to show what I need, and I think it's pretty clear! I will fix the pointer thing anyway. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: As Bryan mentioned, alignment is going to be the major issue here.  There *must* be padding in buffer when it changes types, and I don't believe there's a standard way to determine how much is needed.  Do you know the all possible values of `n` at compile time?  If so, that opens up a few possibilities.  There are also options if `n` is small enough that a bit of memory overhead per element is acceptable, but if you care about contiguous memory, I'm guessing that's not the case.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I also considerer using something like that (like offsetof which, if I remember correctly, is what it is used for container_of), but I haven't found anything that could be used to solve this problem specifically.

Comment: @Ray the original idea was to be able to allocate more memory to the buffer if necessary (reallocating everything) but I'm not sure yet if I'll do it that way. So, could you please tell me how would you create such function if you knew the 'n' for every struct at compile time? Thanks!

Comment: Use a flexible array member (requires that member to be the last in the `struct`). But still you should must not use two different types for that. If you need to store different data, use a nested `union`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way to do this that doesn't play fast and loose with type safety. This means, technically, a truly generic solution will result in undefined behavior. If I was forced to implement something like this, I would have to assume I could treat the incoming structure pointer as an array of pointers. And the size of each type would need to be passed in. Ignoring alignment issues, some untested code:

```
void allocate(void *sp, size_t n, ... /* terminate with 0 */) {
    void **sv = sp;
    size_t arg, total = 0;
    size_t args = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    while ((arg = va_arg(ap, size_t)) != 0) {
        total += arg;
        ++args;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    *sv = calloc(...);
    sv[1] = sv[0];
    va_start(ap, n);
    while (--args > 0) {
        ++sv;
        sv[1] = (char *)sv[0] + va_arg(ap, size_t);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

allocate(a, n, sizeof(type_x), sizeof(type_y), (size_t)0);
allocate(b, n, sizeof(type_w), sizeof(type_y), sizeof(type_z), (size_t)0);
```

Clearly hacky and ugly.

The better solution should really be to create a separate allocator function for each type. However, you can create a macro to aid in the automatic generation of the allocator. More untested code follows:

```
#define CREATE_ALLOCATOR(Type, X_Fields) \
void allocate_##Type (struct Type *sp, size_t n) { \
    _Pragma("pop_macro(\"X\")") \
    size_t total = 0 \
        X_Fields \
        ; \
    void *p; \
    sp->buffer = calloc(sizeof(*sp) + total); \
    p = sp->buffer; \
    _Pragma("pop_macro(\"X\")") \
    X_Fields \
    ; \
}

#include "create_allocator_helper.h"
CREATE_ALLOCATOR(A, X(x) X(y))
#include "create_allocator_helper.h"
CREATE_ALLOCATOR(B, X(w) X(y) X(z))
```

Where the helper header file defines and pushes some X macro definitions used by the `CREATE_ALLOCATOR` macro:

```
#ifdef X
#undef X
#endif
#define X(A) ; sp->A = p; p = sp->A + n
#pragma push_macro("X")
#undef X
#define X(A) + sizeof(sp->A)
#pragma push_macro("X")
#undef X
```

Comment: The inline `_Pragma` syntax is GCC specific in this example, but MSVC has a syntax that is not entirely dissimilar, spelled `__pragma`.

Comment: If you had full C.11 support, you could use the new `_Generic` facility to make a single `allocator()` macro that dispatched to an appropriate type specific allocator.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the set of possible `n`s at compile time, you can let each (member set)/(array size) combination be its own type, and use convenience macros to refer to the correct ones.

```
#include <stddef.h>

/*  
We put a type marker at the beginning of each struct.  There won't be padding before the first member, and all the types
start with a struct Type, so we can do `(struct Type*)&unknown_structure` and be guaranteed to have a valid object that
tells us what type the rest of it is.

In practice, I'd probably use X-Macros to generate an enum containing all the types instead of using strings, to
make comparison faster 
*/

struct Type { char *type; size_t n; };

/* We define what types of arrays each structure contains. Since the struct contains the arrays themselves
instead of pointers to them, the memory will be contiguous, +/- a bit of padding. */

#define DECL_A(N) struct A_##N { struct Type type; char x[N]; double y[N]; }
#define DECL_B(N) struct B_##N { struct Type type; size_t n; int x[N]; float y[N]; char z[N]; }

/* 
Declare a struct and initialize the type and n members.  This one just
declares a local variable, but we could make a malloc version easily enough. 
*/
#define CREATE_STRUCT(NAME, TYPE, N) struct TYPE##_##N NAME = { .type = { #TYPE, N} }

/* We declare all struct type/size combinations we'll use */
DECL_A(42);
DECL_A(100);
DECL_B(30);

int main(void) {
    int i;

    CREATE_STRUCT(foo, A, 42);
    CREATE_STRUCT(bar, A, 100);
    CREATE_STRUCT(baz, B, 30);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that doesn't require `n` to be known at compile time.

Note that I am not *completely* sure about the legality of this, but I'm
reasonably sure it's valid.  The key idea here is that if `p` points to a
properly aligned memory block for type `T`, then `((char*)p) + sizeof(T) * N` must also point
to properly aligned memory as long as it falls within an allocated block.
As long as that's true, I'm pretty sure this must necessarily be legal, since the union
of `buffer` and `Alignment_Hack` guarantees that `buffer[0]` is aligned properly for all types.

Even if it's legal, it's still a bit of a hack, so I'm not entirely sure I'd *recommend* it, but it's a potential option.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* This MUST contain all types that might be stored in the arrays */
union Alignment_Hack {
    short hd;
    int d;
    char c;
    float hf;
    double f;
};

/* This struct is used for *all* structures.  The structure-specific details get specified later */
struct Variable_Structure {
    size_t num_arrays;
    void **arrays;
    union {
        union Alignment_Hack *hack;
        char *buffer;
    } u; //u.buffer[0] is guaranteed to be properly aligned for anything in the union
};

//Here's where the details for a specific struct (struct A {short x; double y; int z; }) are specified.
size_t sizes_A[] = { sizeof(short), sizeof(double), sizeof(int) };


void create_structure(struct Variable_Structure *p, const size_t array_count, size_t *sizes, unsigned nvars) {
    size_t offsets[nvars];//in bytes (NOTE: requires C99)
    unsigned i;

    offsets[0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < nvars; i++) {
        //offsets[i] must be an even multiple of sizes[i] and must also be past the end of the last array
        size_t min = offsets[i - 1] + sizes[i - 1] * array_count;
        size_t mod = min % sizes[i];

        //offsets[i] = min_p such that p >= min and p % sizes[i] == 0
        offsets[i] = (min - mod) + (mod ? sizes[i] : 0);// (min - mod) and (min - mod + sizes[i]) are the two possible starting points

        /* Visualization of the transition from TYPE_A[] to TYPE_B[], showing where everything's pointing:

                                      min (end of TYPE_A array)
                                       V
        ... | TYPE_A | TYPE_A | TYPE_A |
        ...   |  TYPE_B  |  TYPE_B  |  TYPE_B  |  TYPE_B  |
                                    ^          ^
                             min - mod       (min - mod) + sizes[i] */

        assert(offsets[i] >= min);//doesn't overlap previous array
        assert(offsets[i] <= min + sizes[i]);//doesn't include more padding than necessary
        assert(0 == offsets[i] % sizes[i]);//alignment correct
    }
    size_t bufsiz = offsets[nvars - 1] + sizes[nvars - 1] * array_count;

    //Skipping error checking for brevity
    p->num_arrays = nvars;
    p->u.buffer = malloc(bufsiz);
    p->arrays = malloc(sizeof(void*) * nvars);
    for (i = 0; i < nvars; i++) {
        p->arrays[i] = p->u.buffer + offsets[i];
    }
}

void free_structure(struct Variable_Structure *p) {
    free(p->arrays);
    free(p->u.buffer);
}

int main(void) {
    struct Variable_Structure a;

    size_t n = 42;
    create_structure(&a, n, sizes_A, sizeof(sizes_A)/sizeof(*sizes_A));

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //We could always set up some macros or something so we could say, e.g., A(x, i) instead of ((short*)a.arrays[0])[i]
        ((short*)a.arrays[0])[i] = i;
        ((double*)a.arrays[1])[i] = i;
        ((int*)a.arrays[2])[i] = i;

        printf("%hd %f %d\n",
            ((short*)a.arrays[0])[i],
            ((double*)a.arrays[1])[i],
            ((int*)a.arrays[2])[i]);
    }

    printf("SIZES: %zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(short), sizeof(double), sizeof(int));
    printf("OFFSETS: %p %p %p\n", a.arrays[0], a.arrays[1], a.arrays[2]);

    free_structure(&a);
    return 0;
}
```